# Swift: Web Service API call returns error on certain networks

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsurl

I am creating an iOS app using Swift that uses some web services to get some information.  Specifically I am using the food2fork API to get some recipes.  The problem that I'm having is that, if I am connected to the internet at my University, the web calls will always return errors, even though I know that I am connected to the internet on the phone.  I believe that the error has something to do with how the network only will handle secure websites, but I'm not sure.

Am I not using NSURL correctly? Is there a better way that I should do it to ensure that my web calls will always return the data that the app needs?  Here is the function:

```
func getRecipeByID(recipeId: String, sendTo: RecipeInfoViewController)
{
    let theURLAsString = "http://food2fork.com/api/get?key=[MY KEY]&rId=" + recipeId
    let theURL = NSURL(string: theURLAsString)
    let theURLSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let theJSONQuery = theURLSession.dataTaskWithURL(theURL!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if(error != nil)
        {
            print(error!)
        }

        do
        {
            let theJSONResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

           if theJSONResult.count > 0
            {
                let theRecipeDictionary = theJSONResult["recipe"] as? NSDictionary
                sendTo.setRecipeInfo(theRecipeDictionary!)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error) //The function always gets here on certain networks
        }
    })
    theJSONQuery.resume()
}
```

The error that is output at the print(error) line is:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: I think your university may be blocking the `food2fork` website for one reason or another. Did you examine the returned `data` as string?

Comment: It also blocks other web services that I've attempted to use with it.  All appear to be HTTP calls instead of HTTPS, would that be a possible cause?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running iOS 9, you'll need to disable [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/plist/info/NSAppTransportSecurity) for that domain by adding keys to your Info.plist.  Otherwise, you won't be able to make non-HTTPS connections.